# Create a custom ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, actionlink

I want to create a custom actionlink but I don't know how to do this while fulfilling my needs. I worked with custom htmlhelpers before but this is a bit more tricky for me.

**The `actionlink` that I want to call needs to be like this:**

```
@Html.CustomActionLink("LinkText", "Area","Controller","TabMenu","Action",routeValues, htmlAttributes)
```

**so an example would be:**

```
 @Html.CustomActionLink("Click here","Travel","Trip","Index","Index", new { par1 = "test", par2 = test2, new { @class = "font-color-blue" })`
```

**Which would generate this html:**

```
<a class="font-color-blue" href="/Trip/Travel/Index/Index?par1=test&par2=test2">Click Here</a>
```

**And my route looks like:**

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "EPloeg_default",
            "EPloeg/{controller}/{tabmenu}/{action}/{id}/{actionMethod}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, actionMethod = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Any ideas how I can make this?

Comment: What html would that generate?

Comment: Sry forgot, added it in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following code,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here","Trip","Index", new { area= "Travel", tabmenu= "Index"}, new { @class = "font-color-blue" })
```

---

**EDIT**

You can use a extension method like this,

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string area, string controller, string tabMenu, string action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    routeValues.Add("area", area);
    routeValues.Add("tabMenu", tabMenu);
    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: I want it cleaner, thats why I don't want area and tabmenu in my route values when I have lots of parameters.

Comment: then just a matter of creating a extension method and do this inside that

Comment: Check my Edit for the sample extension method

Comment: Apparently the parameters are not getting passed corectly. This is how I call the actionlink :     @Html.CustomActionLink(EnumTranslator.Translate(item.TypeEvaluation), "EPloeg", "Evaluation", Model.TabMenu, "Detail", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = item.Id, actionMethod = Model.ActionMethod }))

Comment: is it passing correctly if you pass all `string` values? and check what are the values not passing

Comment: The RouteValueDictionary type is giving me problems.

Comment: I thought it did but I made a mistake and it still does not work. When I hover over the actionlink I get this url: http://i.imgur.com/8UE05vH.png All parameters are correctly filled in the custom html helper.

Comment: Try this `@Html.CustomActionLink(EnumTranslator.Translate(item.TypeEvaluation), "EPloeg", "Evaluation", Model.TabMenu, "Detail", new { id = item.Id, actionMethod = Model.ActionMethod },null);`

Comment: It is using the wrong overload but I don't get how do I add htmlAttributes if the type is Dictionary<string, object>() ?

Comment: `new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"aaa",value}}` or even you can use any other overload with matching parameters with this idea

Comment: This works but is there a solution where I can pass a new object for htmlAttributes?

Comment: then use `object` instead of `dictionary` in your method implementation. and use that overload

Answer (score 2):

You can implement custom Action Link extensions, you have to write your own method inside `LinkExtensions` class:

```
namespace TestCustomHelper.Html
{

public static class LinkExtensions
{
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool showActionLinkAsDisabled)
  {
     if (htmlHelper.ActionAuthorized(actionName, controllerName))
     {
       return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
     }
     return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}

}
```

and use it in view:

```
@using TestCustomHelper.Html


@Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Create New", "Create", new { org = ViewBag.OrgBranchID }, new { @id = "linkCreateEmployee" },true)
```

### NOTE:

I have added one extara bool parameter if you see the last parameter of the method, you can add more according to your need.

i just wrote one overload for it according to my needs, you can write all overloads as `Html.ActionLink()` has.

See my [**tutorial on Creating Custom Html Helper Extensions in asp.net mvc**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/09/creating-custom-html-helper-extensions.html)

Also see [**Official asp.net mvc Creating Custom HTML Helpers**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

### Update

you may want to see my [this answer in which custom Action Link I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893721/render-link-containing-span-in-asp-net-mvc-razor/28893895#28893895)