# How can I create a Custom ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC that uses T4MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper, t4mvc

I want to create a Custom ActionLink (Custom Html Helper) that uses T4MVC... I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You'll have to explain what exactly you are trying to do and what have you tried.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763232/create-a-custom-actionlink/25763434#25763434