# Razor view Html.ActionLink icon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I need to add an icon near myLink in razor view,
in .html page i use ` Requête optimisée.
Now i have

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Requete optimisée", "Index", "Requete")
```

Dont know where to add my icon .

Comment: you can write a custom helper see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893721/render-link-containing-span-in-asp-net-mvc-razor and also check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535704/image-button-in-actionlink-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use ActionLink and would do the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Requete")" class="my-link-class">Requete optimisée
<div class="my-icon"><img src="@Url.Content("~/icon.jpg")" alt="Icon Image" /></a>
```

More code but also more freedom and control over what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want show an icon just put a `img` tag before your link:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/Image.png" />
@Html.ActionLink("Requete optimisée", "Index", "Requete")
```

And if you want to display image link then use this:

```
@Html.ActionImage("Requete optimisée", "Requete", "~/Content/Images/Image.png")
```