# Putting Html code in html helper generated tag

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this Html code :

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Espace propriétaire du terrain <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

I'd like to use html helper instead of using `a` tag

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Espace propriétaire du terrain ", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "dropdown", data_toggle = "dropdown", role = "button", aria_expanded = "false" })<span class="caret"></span>
```

the problem is that the `span` tag become outside the `a` tag ie in the first code I get the two tags inline but in the second it is placed vertically.

So, How can I change my code to replace the first html code by another using `Html.ActionLink` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Html.ActionLink` you can render a url via `Url.Action` in `href` property of anchor tag because you cannot incorporate any HTML inside the `ActionLink` per se.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Espace propriétaire du terrain <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom extension method to behave the way you want it to.

Reference: http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/10/09/How-To-Create-Custom-MVC-Extension-Methods.aspx

**Example:**

```
  public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string area, string controller, string tabMenu, string action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        routeValues.Add("area", area);
        routeValues.Add("tabMenu", tabMenu);
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Code Src:[Create a custom ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763232/create-a-custom-actionlink)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible per se. `ActionLink` will always encode the given text, so you cannot add the span inside the link description. And putting it after is not the same.

You could probably use CSS rules to make the a tag behave like the span tag does in this case.